# Using a keyboard/mouse with an xbox 360

Tags: python

I was playing an FPS on my Xbox 360 the other night, and I realized how much better I am with a mouse and keyboard on my PC.  So my thought is to run a mouse and keyboard through my Raspberry Pi to my Xbox 360.

Is anyone aware of any projects doing this?  If not, other than xinput, can anyone point me in a good direction?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but to my recollection there are existing off-the-shelf solutions for this already.

Answer (score 2):

You know you can plug in a KB and/or mouse into the USB ports on the 360 right?  The game must support them natively (and there are only a few that do) but it's possible.

The alternative would be, as stated, mod a controller and control it to feed the signals to the 360 to make it think you are pressing the buttons.

The delay in processing input and then generating correct signals for the controller might well add enough lag to make your gaming experience not very nice.  RasPi and Arduino are not really renowned speed demons.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on how to mod your xbox 360 controller [here](http://forum.arcadecontrols.com/index.php?topic=64050.0) 
You would have to do the rest of the moding using a Pi yourself I'm afraid.

A cursory glance at Google and github didn't return me anything useful at least.